# Can't install packages globally with npm

Tags: npm, nvm

I can't install packages globally on windows. Every time I try `npm install -g <pachage>` it installs the package in the current(from where I run this command) folder and not in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm`. Any idea? I am working on Windows 10 and with NVM.

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
npm install <package name> -g
```

for example

```
npm install jshint -g
```

this should work fine. incase you get permission errors.
trying to run your commandline as administrator.

If you are a linux user you should use

```
sudo npm install <package name > -g.
```

hope this works for you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that wasn't my question. I know that I have to use -g to install globbaly and I am using it. However, my package are not installed globally but in the folder I am.

Comment: Read my solution properly.

Comment: you are using -g before the package name. use the -g after the package name

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Follow that and look carefully. If it doesn't work then perhaps you installed node wrongly.